# The method 'registerTeams' isn't defined for the type '_SIFormState'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method,

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, flutter-layout

when I use other files in **main.dart** it show error message. I also try to change the name but it's not work for me[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm calling file.dart instead of class for example I'm calling **registerTeams()** instead of **RegisterTeam()**